# Meaning of this line: (void)(pointer);

Tags: c, embedded

I read this code in TSS project https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tss
This is thier functions

```c
void Tss2_Sys_Finalize(
    TSS2_SYS_CONTEXT *sysContext)
{
    (void)(sysContext);
}
```

I cant understand that syntax "(void)(sysContext);" meaning. Please tell me what it meaning or let me some keyword search about that.
Thank you, and sorry about my bad English.